# How to save all checked value from html page to google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I research the StackOverflow but can't find the answer to my question. I have a webpage contain checkbox elements

```
 <div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="color" value="green">Green
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="color" value="red">Red
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="color" value="blue">Blue
  </label>
</div>
```

I call the jQuery ajax to post the data to google sheet like this

```
var $form = $('form#frm'),
url = '<google script macros url>'

$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function() {
      alert("Form Completed");
    }
  })
})
```

If I check all checkboxes, only the first value "Green" will be saved to google sheet? I don't know how the serialize() prepare the data and post to google sheet, how can I post all checked value? I want to post all checked values in **green,red,blue** format.

Thanks for Tanaike's comment, I enclose the app script here

```
var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet4";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 

function doPost(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; 
    var row = []; 
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ 
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { 
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { 
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about ``<google script macros url>``? Of course, please hide your personal information.

Comment: the url is https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby36pu25cgy1SjWCgy-xJubax254JIItuDB92w7z3PY5Dxydkqs/exec, of course, I change some of the characters

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? At first, please check whether my understanding for your question is correct. If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the detail information for completely replicating the issue? Of course, please hide your personal information. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I add the app script in my question for detail information

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply comment, it was found that the checked values are put to the Spreadsheet. I'm glad for it. But about your new issue, I cannot understand about your goal. Because from your question and additional script, I cannot see the detail vision of your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So now I remove my answer. When I could correctly understand about your goal. I would like to update my answer.

Comment: @Tanaike Appreciate your sample code, it did inspire me I have to focus on the app script also. I am still trying but not yet fix the problem. Looking for your good news.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. I think that I have to study more and more.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot still see the vision about your goal. So if you can do, can you provide your current whole script and a sample Spreadsheet including the result you want to achieve? By this, I would like to think of your solution. Of course, please remove your personal information from samples. Can you do this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem after try and error, here is the code I rewrote

```
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 

function doPost(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; 
    var row = []; 
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ 
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { 
    switch(headers[i]) {
        case "color":         // color is the field in checkbox type 

        // check the field has been answer or not, 
        if(e.parameters[headers[i]] === undefined) {    
          row.push('');
        } else {
          row.push(e.parameters[headers[i]].toString());  // convert the array into string 
        }
          break;
      default:
        if(e.parameter[headers[i]] === undefined) {
          row.push('');
        } else {
          row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]); 
        }
    }

        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { 
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

If the input type is checkbox from the form, the answer will be in an array format, function .toString() method returns a string with all the array values, separated by commas.

```
row.push(e.parameters[headers[i]].toString());
```

I can't find the better function to check whether the parameter is a text or checkbox type, so I use a stupid way to hard code it by using the switch() function. If someone know how to check, please kindly suggest the function call.